# PHP processing with multiple function to return expected result

Tags: php

in this code which is that a simple code to work with passing multiple function we should expected to return `5` in result,

this below method should accept a one variable number of functions, and that should return a new function that accepts one parameter which that `$arg` named

the returned function should call the first function in the `pipeline` with the parameter `$arg` and call the second function with the result of the first function

the returned function should calling each function in the `pipeline` in order, following the same pattern and return the value from the last function

```php
function pipeline(...$funcs)
{
    return function($arg) use ($funcs)
    {
        return -1;
    };
}

$fun = pipeline( function($parameter) { return $parameter * 3; },
                      function($parameter) { return $parameter + 1; },
                      function($parameter) { return $parameter / 2; } );
echo $fun(3); # we should see 5 in output
```

now whats problem of this code which that return `-1`

Comment: See at `pipeline` that you are not using `$funcs` at all, there is just a `-1` hard-coded. That is why it always returns `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the returned function returns `-1` and the functions are never called. You should loop over the functions and call them to alter `$arg`:

```
function pipeline(...$funcs)
{
    return function($arg) use ($funcs)
    {
        foreach ($funcs as $func) {
            $arg = $func($arg);
        }
        return $arg;
    };
}

$fun = pipeline(function($parameter) { return $parameter * 3; },
                function($parameter) { return $parameter + 1; },
                function($parameter) { return $parameter / 2; });
echo $fun(3); # we should see 5 in output
```

Output:

```
5
```